# How can create copyright dynamically with repeater in asp.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, date, repeater

I try to create `@copyright` but like this `@2017`
change the years auto

I want to change it dynamically by years

**How to do that using repeater?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code in your .aspx page if you don't want to use a repeater:

```
<%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy") %>
```

We have used this in our website, see below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Sample Query**

```
<div id="footer" class="footer"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var d = new Date();
        $('#footer').text(d.getFullYear());
    });
</script>
```

**OR**

```
<img src="/images/<%= DateTime.Now.Year %>.png" alt="Copyright" />
```